# Add a tr after a certain device width using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following table which looks like below:

```
<thead>        
    <tr class="footable-pagesize">
        <th align="left">Show</th>
        <th>
            <select id="transaction-per-page" class="float-left">
                <option value="5">50 Per Page</option>
                <option value="10">100 Per Page</option>
                <option value="20">150 Per Page</option>
                <option value="50">200 Per Page</option>
            </select>
        </th>            
        <th data-breakpoints="xs" width="">
            <div id="reportrange"  class="primary-icon dateRangePicker" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 100%">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
                <span></span> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
            </div>
        </th>
        <th data-breakpoints="xs" class="footable-expor-pdf" align="right">
            <a href="" class="primary-icon">  <i class="fas fa-file-pdf fa-2x icon"> </i></a>
            &nbsp;
            <a href="" class="primary-icon">  <i class="fas fa-file-excel fa-2x icon"> </i></a>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th data-breakpoints="xs">Date</th>
        <th data-breakpoints="xs">Description</th>
        <th>Transaction Id</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Now you can see that there are 2 `tr` tags. The first `tr` has 4 `th`.

Now I want to make this first `tr` to be replaced with 2 separate `tr` with 2 `th` in each row(tr) in a certain device width, For e.g: 576px.

I mean this output

```
<thead>        
    <tr class="footable-pagesize">
        <th align="left">Show</th>
        <th>
            <select id="transaction-per-page" class="float-left">
                <option value="5">50 Per Page</option>
                <option value="10">100 Per Page</option>
                <option value="20">150 Per Page</option>
                <option value="50">200 Per Page</option>
            </select>
        </th>  
    </tr>
    <tr>          
        <th data-breakpoints="xs" width="">
            <div id="reportrange"  class="primary-icon dateRangePicker" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 100%">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
                <span></span> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
            </div>
        </th>
        <th data-breakpoints="xs" class="footable-expor-pdf" align="right">
            <a href="" class="primary-icon">  <i class="fas fa-file-pdf fa-2x icon"> </i></a>
            &nbsp;
            <a href="" class="primary-icon">  <i class="fas fa-file-excel fa-2x icon"> </i></a>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th data-breakpoints="xs">Date</th>
        <th data-breakpoints="xs">Description</th>
        <th>Transaction Id</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

How can I do this using jQuery or Javascript?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you want to bind your table according to screen's height and width?

Comment: I don't want to load the table. I need to make the first tr to 2 tr with 2 th in a specific width.

Comment: Is it necessary to do it with js/jquery? You can use CSS `@media`-query

Comment: @schogges Yes, it's necessary to do it using js/jQuery because in a small device I am showing 2 column in a row but need to show 4 heading also. .

Comment: but it's not possible using jQuery / Javascript ?

Comment: can you guys tell me why this jQuery code is not working? `$('.footable-pagesize tr th:nth-child(2)').append('</tr><tr>');`

Comment: You are trying to select a `tr` inside `.footable-pagesize` but there is none inside

Comment: @schogges can you tell me how can I select it then?

Comment: For me its not clear where you want to append the `<tr></tr>`. Directly after `.footable-pagesize` but on the same level?

Comment: @schogges please check my question where I have said that " I mean this output". Here you can see that I have added `<tr></tr>` In first `tr` with 2 `th`. got it?

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){        
    var x = $(window).width(); //You will get device width here..
    var y = $(window).height();//You will get device height here..
    
    // you can remove or append or show/hide your tr according to width
    if(x > 576)
    {
      $('#tr1').css("display", "block");
      $('#tr2').css("display", "none");
      $('#tr3').css("display", "none");      
    }
    else
    {
      $('#tr1').css("display", "none");
      $('#tr2').css("display", "block");
      $('#tr3').css("display", "block");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tblTransaction">
<thead>        
    <tr class="footable-pagesize" id="tr1" style="display:none;">
        <th align="left">Show</th>
        <th>
            <select id="transaction-per-page" class="float-left">
                <option value="5">50 Per Page</option>
                <option value="10">100 Per Page</option>
                <option value="20">150 Per Page</option>
                <option value="50">200 Per Page</option>
            </select>
        </th>            
        <th data-breakpoints="xs" width="">
            <div id="reportrange"  class="primary-icon dateRangePicker" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 100%">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
                <span></span> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
            </div>
        </th>
        <th data-breakpoints="xs" class="footable-expor-pdf" align="right">
            <a href="" class="primary-icon">  <i class="fas fa-file-pdf fa-2x icon"> </i></a>
            &nbsp;
            <a href="" class="primary-icon">  <i class="fas fa-file-excel fa-2x icon"> </i></a>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="footable-pagesize" id="tr2" style="display:none;">
        <th align="left">Show</th>
        <th>
            <select id="transaction-per-page" class="float-left">
                <option value="5">50 Per Page</option>
                <option value="10">100 Per Page</option>
                <option value="20">150 Per Page</option>
                <option value="50">200 Per Page</option>
            </select>
        </th>  
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr3"  style="display:none;">          
        <th data-breakpoints="xs" width="">
            <div id="reportrange"  class="primary-icon dateRangePicker" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 100%">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
                <span></span> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
            </div>
        </th>
        <th data-breakpoints="xs" class="footable-expor-pdf" align="right">
            <a href="" class="primary-icon">  <i class="fas fa-file-pdf fa-2x icon"> </i></a>
            &nbsp;
            <a href="" class="primary-icon">  <i class="fas fa-file-excel fa-2x icon"> </i></a>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th data-breakpoints="xs">Date</th>
        <th data-breakpoints="xs">Description</th>
        <th>Transaction Id</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @bindi but can I use this code? `$('.footable-pagesize tr th:nth-child(2)').append('</tr><tr>');`

Comment: @Shibbir,   Yes, you can find specific tr, append tr or remove existing tr or modify child once you get width. Above snippet was just demo.

Comment: @Shibbir, $(window).width(); will give you width. You can apply your own logic on basis of it's value. I hope this is helpful to you.

Comment: I think if I can add `</tr><tr>` after that first tr -> 2nd th then it will be perfect.

Comment: Yes, you can do it as well. You have to append tr in that case. Please mark it as a answer if it is useful to you. You can refer jquery documentation http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/ for more details.

Comment: well, I am using this code: `$("table thead tr>th:nth-child(2)").after("</tr><tr>");` but not working as expected

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you a possibility how to rearrange the `th`-elements depending on viewport-width using CSS only:

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m6xty0eg/1/)

Comment: Do you know why this is not working? `$("table thead tr>th:nth-child(2)").append("</tr>");`

Comment: Try by using `insertAfter()`
e.g.: `$("<tr></tr>").insertAfter(".footable-pagesize");`

Comment: it's adding like this way :( `<tr></tr>` but it' sshould be `</tr><tr>`

Comment: Sorry I dont get it. Why do you want to append the closing-tag first?
edit: nvm I got it: you want to split your `tr` that way!?

Comment: check my question where I am " I mean this output"

Comment: Ok you can't do it that way. I would recommend using the solution of @bindi.raval or using css only as I showed you in the fiddle. Other possible solutions can be using templates where you check viewport-width first.